# How to send windows domain username and password details from response.varfile?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, windows-7-x64, var

I am installing a software using silent mode in Windows 7. And passing arguments (like installation directory etc) required for this installation  from a response.varfile using the following command:

```
>software.exe -q -varfile response.varfile
```

The above command is working fine.

Now I want to pass the following arguments during the installtion:

```
My system domain username : DOMAINNAME/username
My system Password : Test@123
```

How to specify the above arguments from response.varfile?

Can anybody give an idea on this.